# git commit -S silently fails to sign and continues to commit when using SSH

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up automatic git commit signatures, however whenever I try to run `git commit -am "example"` it successfully makes the commit without signing it.

In my git config I have:

```
...
user.signingkey=/path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
gpg.format=ssh
commit.gpgsign=true
...
```

My SSH key and agent works correctly when I pull or push, however when using `git commit -am "example"` my `git log` shows the unsigned commit, it fails to sign and commits anyways.  I have also tried setting `commit.gpgsign` to `false` and manually signing using `-S` with the same result.

It is as if the `-S` flag is just completely ignored.

EDIT: Additional info.

When I run `git log` after the commit this is the output:

```
commit 4d3bd971f2bfbjdue0d8258e5fae982492082fcd (HEAD -> example)
Author: Example <exmample@domain.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 4 17:25:58 2024 +0200

    example
```

When I run `git cat-file -p HEAD` this is the output:

```
tree 6f812a7caa9b36c25csg6650f469950eba8c9c7b
parent eaf107dadc57f93th87b4d5318896ce1bdc6df8f
author Example <example@domain.com> 1707060358 +0200
committer Example <example@domain.com> 1707060358 +0200
gpgsig -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----
 U1NIU0lHAAAAAQAAADMAAAALc3NoLrgkMjU1MTkAAAAgd+0zpC6Eq8X30s9cXSGFeROpzJ
 xMZKyjlm+30PHKFwEAAAADZ2l0AAAAAAAAAAjdhtE1MTIAAABTAAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5
 AAAAQM+kg8VUWOY6khCCpwvqZykNdtsyrHn7hYIuCYnycdKlriYSA5DQLBoXJG0U2ucQk3
 T1nqGK3MKD5/7TVYV3owc=
 -----END SSH SIGNATURE-----

example
```

If I push that and make a pull request, it fails saying my commit is unverified.

Comment: `git sign` isn't a valid git command. What command are you actually running?

Comment: It was a typo, I updated it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `git log` or `git show` to validate ssh signatures, you must create an "allowed signers" file; see the documentation for [`gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gpgsshallowedSignersFile).

For example, if I configure ssh signing like this:

```
git config gpg.format ssh
git config user.signingKey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
git config commit.gpgsign true
```

And then commit a change in a test repository:

```
echo "This is a test" > example-file
git add example-file
git commit -m "Example commit"
```

`git log` will show "No signature":

```
$ git log --show-signature
error: gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile needs to be configured and exist for ssh signature verification
commit 88d2772f8907d2b429140a466e7c97fa5e2d6e30 (HEAD -> master)
No signature
Author: lars <lars@example.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 4 14:43:31 2024 +0000

    Example commit
```

Note the warning message in the output from that command:

```
error: gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile needs to be configured and exist for ssh signature verification
```

We can confirm that the commit actually has a signature by using `git cat-file`:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree 3f676eeca925687d55ce0be08dbb2923338f09ec
author lars <lars@example.com> 1707057811 +0000
committer lars <lars@example.com> 1707057811 +0000
gpgsig -----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----
 U1NIU0lHAAAAAQAAAZcAAAAHc3NoLXJzYQAAAAMBAAEAAAGBAJyGND3BB04qrqyUITvVZh
 9EBroH7YEZa9RE8Sn0TInwyMT4HNvkNyxTWFjlTC311cFid3HnoKLOH6L5QuGLlSYlJCPM
 K9XmO+rlPifgpSi17ayfTO1t9/rLsNpyqfjBqMpVq5mpcn57KQTceZrEYyikD2R2gh9K01
 lVF72QP87U+QEAIPVatdMrN/MZ1qRz7l8CBH46qj5BOLtfl8dCJinvduW8Y+gyPFqjBkbO
 6Bj2luLDfffSV3BXUVNLhO43W5kkMwycZNqyWXCvVJsZbrn41z2+U138WQyLb6riQWai9r
 9vG31dvPf/Vuqc7PnR1ZGM1ZWo/deaJySrF9xrvie1Vv3YmLEC645HCN9/tOvc6TllNmvs
 B6wY373bUrtVT0Kun1OsIYDKBCuM9Xo6n6TSjUjkxkbwte/haPRcIGYNPoE5kVceVwgGvx
 tBjoKJxe6eH6ugfh17/28QTJ0v1JUO+EgxWIc0FYtbbdyf/dl/rFtZsWL3bx9iMptbVp6Y
 3QAAAANnaXQAAAAAAAAABnNoYTUxMgAAAZQAAAAMcnNhLXNoYTItNTEyAAABgIgBygW+mh
 I1EsC2LoBtOaNjrZWtiisO+9KmDMBuAn2n15JHt3h+6BwODLqEqcLiBzTJVZoQZVgdlNrF
 jKhY1PhNqewy9CvDF+n4j9V85+LbOOktWLodx7KJ8Epfv4z6QlqR4shohH12c7fAWRKsJ9
 zH+bB9L29uuZqfqHyNJFlox9fZsPTAerY/VLoa/j/ij2uGgM+/18d93Gc13GMSdqf+CrF1
 bVZ/j1SE4cneR/YbFI4A3n23iqqCwQoE07WtrYE9b27jnDkoURQi98QJ1YKUS0Jrv1+iap
 ntnXwDSs25FxHQOytBPyf075rMsH6ZnKL/ycSRbGA8dezeivmJJ26uOwGjPEy9FXguqRk8
 W1t4om6vh9BtKTiPVqwoISfQ7CZytZLZ4jzzG6+txjXQtSgVj0HaPXXsYXx8vTYOAkodxO
 RtxQeoDhXk9ReX5QtqHpjR0Z7Ozo5f5PRyVkb/qI6p+Hbq/Qqrkg13OvFv1THrAL0Sxntk
 vbg6zBTk+VB1Sg==
 -----END SSH SIGNATURE-----
```

For git to verify that commit, we need to create an allowed signers file:

```
echo "lars@example.com $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" > ~/.config/git/allowed-signers
git config gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile '~/.config/git/allowed-signers'
```

And now we see the signature verification in the output of `git log --show-signature`:

```
$ git log --show-signature
commit 88d2772f8907d2b429140a466e7c97fa5e2d6e30 (HEAD -> master)
Good "git" signature for lars@example.com with RSA key SHA256:nqEzGFF0Z1rMkovqKg4yIbbyViKTuq4ugzhNIh8ggok
Author: lars <lars@example.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 4 14:43:31 2024 +0000

    Example commit
```

---

If the problem is that *GitHub* is not verifying your signed commits, you need to be sure that you have added your public key to GitHub as a *signing* key. That means that from your "SSH and GPG keys" settings, when you add a key, ensure that "Key type" is set to "Signing":

[image: Key type menu showing that "Signing key" is selected]

Once added, the key will be listed under "Signing keys" on the "SSH and GPG keys" page:

[image: A new key listed under "Signing keys"]

You can find GitHub's documentation on this topic [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification).

Comment: I do not get the error you see, mine just shows the commit without any errors.  I tried to create a signers file now with the same result, it still just fails to sign and continues to commit without any errors.

Comment: Well, start with the diagnostics I've suggested here: if you run `git cat-file -p HEAD` after making a signed commit, what is the output? Please update your question (the output won't format correctly in a comment).

Comment: I've updated as requested.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your comment helped me figure out what's going on, when I saw the output is showing it's signed, I realized the issue is somewhere else.  On GitHub I had different emails on different keys, and the one I was using to sign was set to "Authentication" key, not "Signing" key, so the signing was working correctly, it was just never accepted and verified by GitHub itself.  If you add that to your answer I'll mark it as accepted so you get the credit.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some notes about github.